# Searchview setQuery in Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have got Activity extends AppCompatActivity. I want to set searchview query after change screen orientation. I got NPE error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setQuery(java.lang.CharSequence, boolean)' on a null object reference
```

If i use setQuery in Fragment it works right. In Activity it does not work.
How can I change searchview query from activity ?

MyActivity.java

```
@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bankmvp_menu, menu);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
    searchManager = (SearchManager) this.getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(this.getComponentName()));
    getObservableSearchViewText();
    return true;
}


@Override public void setQueryToSearch(String querystring) {

        searchView.setQuery(querystring, true); //NPE error

}
```

bankmvp_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MyActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_setmonth"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_setmonth"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_setaccount"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_setaccount"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_nosaveddoc"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_nosaveddoc"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Comment: your error log is different from your question, where are you using `.post()` or any thread, share that code

Comment: @ Abdul Kawee I am sorry. I have pasted wrong logcat. I have edited my answer with right logcat. I call setQueryToSearch from my MVP presenter.

Answer (score 0):

To set query string from the Presenter to Searchview

1. Change menu.xml

   ```
   android:id="@+id/action_search"
   android:orderInCategory="100"
   android:title="@string/action_search"
   android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
   app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
   android:iconifiedByDefault="true" //important
   app:showAsAction="always" //important
   ```
2. Change activity, from Presenter set only string.

   ```
   @Override public void setQueryToSearch(String querystringx) {

     if( querystringx.equals("")){
     }else {
       querystring = querystringx;
     }

   }
   ```
3. Change activity setQuery in onResume of activity

   ```
   if( querystring.equals("")){

   }else {
       searchView.setIconified(false);
       searchView.setQuery(querystring, false);
       menuItem.setVisible(true);
   }
   ```

Screen after change orientation

[image]